# How do I show this relationship of 2 differentials?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, physics

If I have some $H = U + pV$, where $dU = TdS - pdV$,  how do I show for some varying $H$, $S$, $p$ that $$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_S$$
which will then further show that
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_V - \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_p = 1$$
by considering $U$ as a function of $p$ and $V$ and considering two expressions for $\partial^2U/\partial p \partial V$.

What I have done:

1. Looking at the question at first, I'm thinking that I should first integrate $dU$ to get $U = Ts - pV$, which I then plug back into the first equation concerning $H$.
2. Then I would have $H = TS$. But this doesn't contain $p$ in it, so it is hard to find the partial derivatives as required.
3. Looking at $dU = TdS - pdV$, I can make an expression of $\frac{dV}{dS}$ but this is not a partial derivative.

Comment: You surely computed the antiderivative incorrectly. The derivative of $TS - pV$ is given by $$ \mathrm{d}(TS - pV) = T \mathrm{d}S + S \mathrm{d}T - p \mathrm{d}V - V \mathrm{d}p$$. If it were true that $U = TS - pV$, then you would have $S\mathrm{d}T  = V \mathrm{d}p$.

Comment: What does the notation such as $\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right)_p$ mean? Does it meant to take the partial derivative as $p$ is held constant? I don't think that is meaningful given the problem -- you have six variables and only two equations. So if you impose $\mathrm{d}p = 0$, you still have no right to expect a linear dependence between $\mathrm{d}V$ and $\mathrm{d}S$. You need to specify two more variables to be held constant for the partial derivative to be meaningful.

Comment: I'm not too sure how else I could compute the antiderivative in this case, as I simply integrated the infinitesimals. Is there another way I could do so?

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes you are right it means $p$ is constant as you perform partial derivative. Unfortunately that is how the question is phrased so I've no clue about this too...

Comment: I have just checked the hint for the problem and edited the question

Comment: So... one of the hypotheses of the problem is that there are only supposed to be two independent degrees of freedom? Are you omitting any hypotheses? Like, is $H$ supposed to be constant?

Comment: Okay, I see there is another implicit equation; $0 = \mathrm{d}(\mathrm{d}U) = \mathrm{d}T \mathrm{d}S - \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}V$, so we can infer more than is immediately obvious.

Comment: The problem with "integrating the integrating the infinitesimals" is that that only works if the coefficient out front is constant. You wouldn't say $\int y \, \mathrm{dx} = xy$, for example, if it happened that $y = x^2$.

Comment: Regarding the hypothesis, I'm not sure actually but I suppose that is not an unreasonable assumption. The question doesn't say anything about the degrees of freedom unfortunately.

Comment: Also some check seems to confirm the validity of $dU = TdS - pdV$ as it's the first law of thermodynamics apparently.

Comment: oldselflearner1959: I'd recommend you mention the context of thermo in the original problem, as there are relationships present that can affect your results. Also, it explains your notation right away.

Comment: @AdrianKeister thanks I have made the physics tag edit.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959: I would actually add some text in the beginning of the question like this, "This question arises in the context of classical thermodynamics".

Comment: @AdrianKeister Actually to be fair, this question was produced in a math text and assumes no knowledge of physics.. so I actually don't know knowing it's classical thermodynamics would help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

*For the first part.*

We have that the enthalpy $H = U + pV$, so $$\mathrm dH=\mathrm dU+p\,\mathrm dV+V\,\mathrm dp\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\mathrm d H= T\,\mathrm d S+V\,\mathrm d p$$

Now $H=H(S,p)$ so that
$$\mathrm d H=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_p\,\mathrm d S+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)_S\,\mathrm d p\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_p=T\quad\text{and}\quad  \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)_S=V$$
For the differential form of $H$ to be exact the second derivatives of both 
terms in the differential are equal, i.e.
$$\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial S}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)_S\right)_p=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_p\right)_S $$ 
that is
$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_S$$

Now you can prove the second part.